# Creating a power button with an NES?

Tags: power, reset

I have an NES that I am creating into an Rpi case. I want to try to do the following:

*Connect the power button to my Rpi to 
1: Turn on the Rpi when pressed in (On)
2: Run a shutdown command regardless of what is happening when pressed out (Off)

*Connect the reset button to
1: When pressed, exit the current program and return to a menu
2: When pressed for a few seconds, reset the system

I am new to this sort of thing. I've seen people do things like this with GPIO, but I don't even know what to do with that. What should I do for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Lucky for you, there is an open source circuit that can do more or less the same thing :) Check out [Pi-Supply](http://www.pi-supply.com/product/pi-supply-raspberry-pi-power-switch/)

You can run a python script to be able to manipulate your GPIO. If you can understand the logic behind pi-supply's [soft shutdown script](http://www.pi-supply.com/pi-supply-switch-v1-1-code-examples/), you can easily do whatever you want regarding this issue.